# Python request parameter unix timestamp

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get the JSON response from this URL:

```
import time
from time import mktime
import requests
import json

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
           "jobCity":"null",
           "jobSkill":"null",
            "pageNumber":1,
            "userText":"",
           "jobTitleOrder":"null",
           "jobCityOrder":"null",
           "jobFunctionOrder":"null",
           "jobExperienceOrder":"null",
           "applyByOrder":"null",
           "regular":"true",
           "walkin":"true"
           }

response = requests.post(url="https://ibegin.tcs.com/iBegin/api/v1/jobs/searchJ?at=",headers=header,json=payload,params=str(long((time.time()) * 1000)))
json_obj = json.loads(response.text)
print json_obj
```

But the print result is empty :

```
 {u'message': u'Ok.', u'data': {u'jobs': [], u'totalJobs': 0}, u'result': u'Y'}
```

instead of this :

```
{"message":"Ok.","result":"Y","data":{"totalJobs":50,"jobs":[{"id":"120315J","jobTitle":"Python Developer ","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"1-10","applyByDate":"27-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"Python","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120281J","jobTitle":"Java Developer","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"3-8","applyByDate":"21-MAY-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"J2EE , Java","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120280J","jobTitle":"Aws Tech Lead","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"8-12","applyByDate":"30-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"AWS redshift , Cloud AWS/Amazon","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120277J","jobTitle":"Technical Support Executive","location":"Singapore","functionName":"IT INFRASTRUCTURE SERVICES","experience":"0-3","applyByDate":"30-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"IT Infrastructure ","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120276J","jobTitle":"Java Developer","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"3-6","applyByDate":"30-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"EJB , Weblogic Server , Java , JMS , Eclipse","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120273J","jobTitle":"Aws Technical Lead","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"5-10","applyByDate":"23-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"AWS , AWS Deployment","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120209J","jobTitle":"Sap Fico Consultant","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"4-10","applyByDate":"18-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"SAP FICO","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"120094J","jobTitle":"Apo Consultant","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"8-10","applyByDate":"10-APR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"SAP APO SNP , SAP APO","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"119352J","jobTitle":"Software Engineer (Java/J2ee)","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"3-10","applyByDate":"31-MAR-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"J2EE , Angular JS , Java","walkin":"J","url":null},{"id":"119234J","jobTitle":"Ui Developer","location":"Singapore","functionName":"TECHNOLOGY","experience":"4-8","applyByDate":"01-MAY-2018 11:59:59 PM","skills":"Javascript , Node JS , TypeScript , BackboneJS , Angular JS , HTML","walkin":"J","url":null}]}}
```

Is there anything more I need to add to the request statement?

Comment: if you try the same request in Postman, does it return the right data?

Comment: Make the request in a web browser and examine it in the Network dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code it seems there is nothing wrong with the code: You POSTed a requested and got no (job) results, nothing wrong with that. Perhaps tweeking the JSON parameters used for the POST request will produce some results

Comment: Yes, it appears I don't have to take every parameter, so I remove several parameters and I got the job result right. Thanks.